# How can I use bash environment variables in IPython?

Tags: environment-variables, ipython

In .bashrc, I usually set a lot of environment variables to store path names.

So, I can go to that specific directory as follows:

```
cd $PARTICULAR_DIR
```

Are there any was to do this in IPython?
The above command doesn't work, so I tried the following:

```
cd os.environ['PARTICULAR_DIR']
```

But the above one also doesn't work.

Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: `os.environ` is Python (though mapping item access uses `[]`), but you seem to have forgotten about `cd`.

Comment: Thanks, the original cd os.environ('PARTICULAR_DIR') was my mistake. I changed it to cd os.environ['PARTICULAR_DIR']. But anyway, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `os.chdir(os.environ[PARTICULAR_DIR'])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use shell commands in IPython. Just prefix with  `!`:

```
In [1]: !ls $PARTICULAR_DIR
```

Unfortunately, `!cd`  does not work because the command is run in a separate shell that is discarded immediately after execution.

You can set bookmarks in IPython:

```
%bookmark <name> <dir>
```

set the name `<name>` as shortcut for `<dir>`.

This procedure would work.

1. Display the path in the variable:

   ```
   In [2]: !echo $PARTICULAR_DIR
   /path/to/dir/
   ```
2. Create a new bookmark with copy and paste:

   ```
   In [3]: %bookmark PARTICULAR_DIR /path/to/dir/
   ```
3. Switch to your desired dir:

   ```
   In [4]: %cd -b PARTICULAR_DIR
   ```

Bookmarks will persist through IPython sessions.

Comment: Syntactically that will work. Try getting your current working directory `os.getcwd()` and you'll be surprised it isn't in the directory you expected.

Comment: @alvits Thanks for hint. `cd` does not as expected because it runs in separate shell. Added workaround to my answer.